# How to undo and redo gesture handling

Tags: nsmutablearray, uigesturerecognizer, nsundomanager

I have written an App without Core Data. Now I want to include methods to realize undo and redo WITHOUT Core Data. 
Unfortunately I found nothing on the internet, books etc.

I thought that I have two NSMutableArray which should have the funktion of stacks. 
So I call them undoStack and redoStack. If I do an action such as gestures, this action should be hold in the array:

> [undoStack addObject: gestureRecognizer];

If I click the button undo, following statements should be performed:

> [undoStack removeObject: [undoStack lastObject]];
>      and
>
> [redoStack addObject: [undoStack lastObject]];

At the end I have got a save button which clears the stacks automatically

That's all well and good, but how can I save all actions in one array? 
Actions like: panGesture, pinchGesture and rotationGesture

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Add all actions to `NSMutableArray` (panGesture, pinchGesture, rotationGesture), then add that array to `undoStack` array. And work with it like with one object. Only when you need to use it you need to extract it. Or you can for example if you have `4 gestures`, then add all gestures to `undoStack`, and when you need to move them to `redoStack`, take 4 last objects and add to `redoStack`.

Comment: Thank you I am really impressed by your answer, I will comment again when I'll give it a try :) but now you get the +1